# mysql selecting room types issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

i have two tables as below, **For each hotel** there will be **room types** and for each **room type there will be rooms**..So under each hotel i want to show the **room types assigned to them and all the rooms assigned to that room type**.

**Room types Table**

```
ID  || NAME || hotel_id ||
1   || a    ||    33    ||
2   || b    ||    55    ||
3   || c    ||    33    ||
```

**Rooms Table**

```
ROOM_ID || ROOM_TYPE_ID  || hotel_id || checkin      || checkout     ||
1       ||   1           ||    33    || 2015-02-04   || 2015-02-08   ||
2       ||   2           ||    55    || 2015-02-24   || 2015-02-28   ||
3       ||   3           ||    33    || 2015-04-14   || 2015-03-18   ||
4       ||   3           ||    33    || 2015-04-18   || 2015-03-28   ||
```

The result should be something like this

```
Hotel id = 33

room types = a,c
rooms      = 1,2
```

I tried the below join it works but not what i want

```
SELECT r.* FROM rooms r JOIN room_types rt ON rt.room_type_id = r.room_id WHERE r.hotel_id  = '" . (int)$hotel_id . "'
```

*how result should be**

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKXcp.png][1]

Thank you!

Comment: Your example result is not accurate...? Hotel ID has rooms 1,3,4 not 1,2

Comment: why hotel_id in both the tables?

Comment: the hotel has rooms, and room types...

Comment: I think you should check group concat

Comment: @Salketer: His example is correct. 1,2 are the total number of rooms under respective room types.

Comment: @KishoreKumar I have not seen anywhere that he wants the count...

Comment: i need something like [agoda.com](http://agoda.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have no sql server on my hand, so you could need to debug this a little:

```
"SELECT COUNT(r.room_id) as rooms , rt.*
FROM rooms r 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM room_types 
  WHERE hotel_id  = 33
    AND name in ('a','c') ) 
AS rt 
ON rt.id = r.room_type_id 
WHERE r.room_id in ( 1, 2 )
GROUP BY rt.id"
```

Comment: can't open the link, and I see no reason to open that. you want me to write full php code? with html and css ?? you have no expirience with php+PDO ? you need help with what part of development?

Comment: i tried your sql but its not out putting what i want...i want simply to show the room types for each hotels and the rooms assigned to each room type..please help me..thanks

Comment: what did you get using my query??

Comment: it just repeated three times..that hotel have only one room type and two rooms for that room type..so it should output the room type just once only

Comment: according to data provided, you have 3 rooms in hotel 33, with two roomtypes 1 with room_type_id=1 and 2 with room_type_id=3. that's  why query return 3 rows, so you want just 2 rows with counter of rooms? sop if there is 5 rooms same type in hote - it must return just one row?

Comment: i don't want to show the rooms but i want the room types..so inside room types only i'm showing no of rooms available..something like agoda.com display their rooms..

Comment: wow your so great man....this works as exactly i wanted..Thanks alot buddy..Great help..Thanks again :)

Comment: you are welcome :-) just try to ask in proper way :-) we can find solution much faster then :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are joining on the wrong columns, try:

```
SELECT r.*,rt.* FROM rooms r JOIN room_types rt ON rt.ID = r.ROOM_TYPE_ID AND r.hotel_id = rt.hotel_id WHERE r.hotel_id  = '" . (int)$hotel_id . "'
```

Comment: This doesn't show what i want..as in lets say i have just one room type and for that room type there are two rooms..so i just want to show the room type but inside that room should show the rooms assigned to that..Thanks

Comment: check agoda.com..i want something like that

Answer (score 0):

Select rty.name, rta.room_id from rooms rta, roomsType rty where rta.ROOM_TYPE_ID=rty.ID and rta.ROOM_ID=33

I think it's, better to you, use lists.
Then, you format the resultset as you like.